# Person who involves in sexual harassment

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is there a proper word for describing the person who involves in sexual harassment.? I thought that it would be sexual harasser, but i am not sure whether it is right or wrong. Can anyone point the right word to represent such persons..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using [harasser](http://www.eeoc.gov/laws/types/sexual_harassment.cfm), which is used by the U.S. Equal Employment Opportunity Commission to describe sexual harassment in the workplace. [Sexual harasser](http://webcms.unk.edu/offices/aaeo/policies/Could_I_be_a_Sexual_Harasser_/) is also used, though probably to a lesser extent, based a cursory search on the Internet. It does show up in such places as the [The University of Nebraska at Kearney website](http://webcms.unk.edu/offices/aaeo/policies/Could_I_be_a_Sexual_Harasser_/) and the academic literature on sexual harassment ([Example article 1](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02621113#page-1); [Example article 2](http://hum.sagepub.com/content/56/12/1461.abstract)).

The [Wikipedia article on sexual harassment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_harassment) contains these additional classes of harassers:

- Public harasser
- Private harasser
- Predatory harasser
- Dominant harasser
- Street harasser

More generally (and perhaps for more severe incidents), the word [perpetrator](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perpetrate) can be used to describe someone who perpetrates wrongdoing such as sexual harassment. This [journal article](http://hum.sagepub.com/content/56/12/1461.abstract), for example, refers to "sexual harassment perpetrators."

Some of the people who have been accused of sexual harassment are listed in the [National Sexual Harassment Registry](http://www.ebosswatch.com/National-sexual-harassment-registry).

FYI, all of this information is available via Google search.

Comment: I am sorry but people who are sexual harassing in the workplace are not sex offenders or on the national registry.  This is very confusing and if perpetrator is your answer I would take the rest out.  The context is different.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd Thanks, I edited my answer to reflect your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

It is a serious accusation, and open to interpretation, so normally one would use careful language such as "the person alleged to have harassed" unless some legal judgement has been rendered.

The [Ontario labour laws](http://www.labour.gov.on.ca/english/hs/sawo/pubs/fs_workplaceviolence.php) on workplace harassment (not just sexual) seem to avoid such references entirely. Their definition is "Engaging in a course of vexatious comment or conduct against a worker in a workplace that is known or ought reasonably to be known to be unwelcome".

Comment: "ought reasonably to be known to be unwelcome" aaaah… Canada…

Answer (score 0):

I think the non-legal normal name we would give to such a person is **pervert**.

> "My pervert boss slaps my ass when ever he tells me something."

Comment: I think 'pervert' has much  stronger implications than sexual harasser!

Comment: Also anyone who upvoted Josh's statement would like to know why and if you are a native English speaker.

Answer (score -1):

He can be defined also **sexual abuser** or **sexual offender** , but your definition  fits  very well,

Comment: Both of these insinuate much more than harassment.

Comment: **Offender** in particular suggests someone who has been convicted of committing a criminal act.

Answer (score -1):

*Sex pest, stalker* and *kerb crawler* are also possible, depending on the situation.

Answer (score -1):

The proper word depends upon the seriousness of the harassment and the response of the harassed person.  It could be anything from "jerk" to "defendant".